How to Fix "Expected a Step" Error in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline?
I am trying to send the build status to Bitbucket after my Jenkins pipeline completes. Here is the relevant part of my Jenkinsfile:
   post {
    always {
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'src/**/*.exe', allowEmptyArchive: true
        cleanWs()
    }
    success {
        steps {
            script {
                def buildStatus = currentBuild.result ?: 'SUCCESS'
                bitbucketBuildStatusNotifier(
                    buildState: buildStatus,
                    credentialsId: 'my_id',
                    repositoryOwner: 'my_repo',
                    repositorySlug: 'my_repo'
                )
            }
        }
    }
    failure {
        steps {
            script {
                def buildStatus = currentBuild.result ?: 'FAILURE'
                bitbucketBuildStatusNotifier(
                    buildState: buildStatus,
                    credentialsId: 'my_id',
                    repositoryOwner: 'my_repo',
                    repositorySlug: 'my_repo'
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

However, I am getting the following errors:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 66: Expected a step @ line 66, column 17.
                   def buildStatus = currentBuild.result ?: 'SUCCESS' 
                   ^

WorkflowScript: 65: Invalid condition "script" - valid conditions are [always, changed, fixed, regression, aborted, success, unsuccessful, unstable, failure, notBuilt, cleanup] @ line 65, column 13.
         script {
           ^

I have tried various modifications, but I keep getting the same errors. How can I properly fix these issues and send the build status to Bitbucket successfully?
The entire Jenkinsfile has stages for cloning the repository, building the project, and performing static code analysis with SonarQube and Cppcheck. The problem specifically occurs in the post section.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I cannot reproduce the specified error with the provided code.

AFAIR, you can't use steps block within the post blocks. Instead, you can use the steps directly, as you already do for always:
post {
  success {        
    script {
      def buildStatus = currentBuild.result ?: 'SUCCESS'
      bitbucketBuildStatusNotifier(
        buildState: buildStatus,
        credentialsId: 'my_id',
        repositoryOwner: 'my_repo',
        repositorySlug: 'my_repo'
      )
    }
  }
}

But the real problem in your case is that you don't really need this:

currentBuild.result is always defined so creating a custom variable with a default value doesn't make sense;
multibranch pipelines (I hope you use them - if you don't, consider starting) automatically report the build status to Bitbucket so sending it manually also doesn't make sense;
finally, even if you decide to do that - you can have much more post conditions and statuses than success and failure, so it makes sense either to do that within the always block only, or refrain from doing that at all (due to the reasons listed above).

